# Splitting field of $x^{p^{n}}-1\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}\left[x\right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

I'm trying to find the splitting field of $x^{p^{n}}-1\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}\left[x\right]$ where $p$ is a prime and integer $n\geq1$.

If $\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{p^{n}}$ are the roots then $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\left(\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{p^{n}}\right)$ is the splitting field, but what do elements of this field look like exactly?

I've factored $x^{p^{n}}-1$ as follows but I'm not sure what else to do $$\begin{align*}
x^{p^{n}}-1 & =\left(x-1\right)\frac{x^{p^{n}}-1}{x-1}\\
 & =\left(x-1\right)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^{p^{i+1}}-1}{x^{p^{i}}-1}\\
 & =\left(x-1\right)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}x^{p^{i}j}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean $x^{p^n}-x$. A field $F$ of characteristic $p$ satisfies $|F|=p^k$ for some integer $k$, so $|F^×|=|F \setminus \{0\}|$ $=p^k-1$. Thus as $p$ does not divide $p^k-1$ for any positive integer $k$, it follows by Lagrange's Thm that $|F^×|$ cannot have any group closed under multipication of order that is a multiple of $p$.

In a field $F$ of size $p^n$, all $p^n$ elements $\alpha \in F$ satisfy $\alpha^{p^n}-\alpha = 0$. So as the number of roots of $p(x)=x^{p^n}-x$ that are in $F$ is deg$(p)$, it follows that the polynomial $p(x)=x^{p^n}-x$ splits in $F$.

---

Meanwhile in characteristic $p$ note that $(x-1)^{p^n}=x^{p^n}-1$. So $1$ is a root w multiplicity $p^n$; i.e., $x^{p^n}-1$ factors completely in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ to $(x-1)^{p^n}$. And thus the splitting field is simply the $p$-element field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Right, plus 1. Without further explanation from OP, we can’t know what “$\Bbb Z_p$” means to them, nor whether they really meant $X^{p^n}-1$ or $X^{p^n}-X$. I might also point out that the latter polynomial is important in the $p$-adic context too…

Comment: @Lubin nice answer below! Yes, you are correct, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ should indeed be used to denote the $p$-adic integers only, but here it seems most everyone [mis]uses $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to mean $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I agree about the (mis)use, but there are very many topologists for whom $\Bbb Z_p$ is $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$; I’m not sure  whether they mean the field or the cyclic group. Anyway, who am I to stand up against all those topologists?

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming that $\Bbb Z_p$ means the ring of $p$-adic integers.

And if you really mean the polynomial $X^{p^n}-1$, i.e. if you’re really asking about the field of $p^n$-th roots of unity, then you may want to do the investigation in steps.

First, the $p$-th roots of unity, with minimal polynomial $X^{p-1}+X^{p-2}+\cdots+X^2+X+1$. By making the substitution $X=T+1$, you get a polynomial whose roots are of form $\zeta_p-1$, for primitive $p$-th roots of unity $\zeta_p$. You do the expansion and see that you have an Eisenstein polynomial of degree $p-1$, so this, your first level, is tamely ramified of degree $p-1$.

In succeeding degrees, the extensions are wild; each succeeding layer is (totally) wildly ramified of degree $p$. The whole extension thus is of degree $p^n-p^{n-1}$, with tame degree $p-1$ and wild degree $p^{n-1}$.

These extensions are important in the proof of the Local Kronecker-Weber Theorem. The global K-W Thm. says that the maximal abelian extension of $\Bbb Q$ is gotten by adjoining all roots of unity.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying in the question, I mean $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ to be the finite field of order $p$

Comment: Beautiful answer